# JS Bootstrap tabbed panel, loading a URL on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap tabbed panel to reload itself on click of the button rather than just show the tab. So clicking on the "office" tab will reload the page, and then have the #office tab showing. I have it all working... except for the page reload. It never fires.

HTML

```
    <div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>     </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a id="office" href="#office" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Office</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">Home</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="office">Office</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery("#office").click(function(e){
            console.log("clicked")
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.replace = "http://www.myurl.com#office";
            console.log("after")

            return false;

        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zxLt5z2r/

Updated Codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOqrvY

Comment: That's not really the right approach. You should be using Bootstrap's built-in callbacks to reload your content, not the tab.

Comment: remove the e.preventDefault() and remove the return false

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false and also calling preventDefault();

```
jQuery("#office").click(function(e){
            console.log("clicked")
            window.location.href = "http://www.myurl.com#office";
            console.log("after")
        });
```

Also, use `window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";`

Comment: @Kris not really, this uses window.location.href. Also you are implying that any solution would be a copy of your comment as this is the only way to do it. Sorry, this is something rather basic no?

Comment: Thanks,but this still doesn't work. See this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOqrvY

Answer (score 0):

Location.replace() is a function that takes an URL as the parameter.

Try:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.myurl.com#office");
```

Comment: Thanks , but the new url is never loaded, and I can't work out why. See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOqrvY

Comment: @Kiksy Your code not working because the id attribute of "office" is assigned to the wrong element. You should assign it to the tab button instead of the tab panel. Check out this one: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaGQWL

Comment: using that one: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaGQWL The new url doesn't open, and the tabs don't seem to work?

Comment: Sorry the tab issue is my fault, I update the codepen to fix that. The thing is you need to bind the click event to the button not the tab. Otherwise the click event won't fire correctly. The URL doesn't open because http://www.myurl.com#office is a pseudo URL and you cannot load it with in the codepen as well. I changed it under the same domain as the codepen.